# ASP.NET Core 3.0 security issue with Http2 on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net-core, http2, kestrel-http-server

I have a few VS 2019 projects that some colleagues created and that I downloaded and attempted to run.  Straight out of the box with no modification, Chrome and Firefox both complain (Edge does not.)

I am running this using Kestrel, by the way.

**Chrome:**
"This site can’t be reached
The webpage at https://localhost:5001/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY"

**Firefox**
Your connection is not secure... blah blah... 
NS_ERROR_NET_INADEQUATE_SECURITY

I have used the workaround in appsettings.json:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1"
    }
```

However, simply regressing to Http1 isn't a solution, it's just a workaround.  I'm also not sure why my colleagues are not experiencing this problem, and I am not.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a solution already but since I didn't find a good solution on my end here's my situation:  I migrated an aspnet core 2.2 project to core 3.  Kestrel in debug (which worked fine prior to migration) would always use the old invalid cert which gave me NS_ERROR_NET_INADEQUATE_SECURITY.  What fixed it on my end was commenting out the UserSecretsId line from my csproj.  After that everything started working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your TLS setup as HTTP/2 blacklists most older, more insecure ciphers [as listed in the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#appendix-A) and may not allow the connection to use HTTP/2 if they are used. You should configure your web server to use more modern GCM ciphers like TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

Comment: Added a few more details. However The answer is still correct - upgrade the cipher because HTTP/2 will not be used over weaker ones. From what cipher and to what cipher depends on exactly they have configured now and what is available to them, which OP has not detailed.

Comment: Fair, the answer was just real light... but re-reading, I agree.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on the issue, but just for clarification purposes:  my colleagues have the exact same code and other files as I do when I downloaded this application.  Theirs works with no errors/warnings.  Mine does not.

So, when you say to "check your TLS setup..." etc., are you referring to some setting on my machine (e.g., via Windows defender, McAfee, or some other application controlling the protocols?)  When you say to "configure my web server", my assumption is to modify the appsettings.json, but that doesn't explain why mine doesn't work, and theirs does WITHOUT modification.

Comment: OK lets get to the differences with some questions. 1) Does theirs work from your machine or have you only tests your own machines (this is to rule out if you have anti-virus causing the problem). 2) Can you use HTTP/2 on other sites? 3) What OS and version are you both running your web server on? I presume Windows but please confirm. 4) Can you confirm you are connecting directly to Kestrel and not via IIS or other web server? 5) Can you give you a minimal reproduction of the issue (code and configuration)? 6) Can you confirm this minimal reproduction works on your friends machine?